# How to include a CCK on a page using Panels

Tags: entities, panels, 7

I am trying to add display a CCK on page using panels

Initially , i created a Contact Us form CCk. Now i want the contact form to be displayed on a page, so that anonymous users can input their information from that page.

**UPDATE**
yes i am able to show the contact form on the page, but it only displays when admin is logged in. But it must be visible to all anonymous users as well

Please help

Comment: Did you check the permissions for the content type you created? Are you running Drupal 7? If so, why are you using CCK? Are you aware that there is a built in contact form: https://drupal.org/node/124129 and a module for extending the contact form: https://drupal.org/project/contact_forms

Comment: Hey thank you so much i just installed the module. It worked.